# Tkinter Button Callback Lambda Unexpected Result

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create multiple rows of `tkinter` widgets and I thought storing them in a dictionary would be a clean way to do this. I'm having trouble getting the callbacks for the buttons to work correctly though. With the code as is, the value passed to the button callback is always `E` and I can't see why that is. How do I pass the correct key to the callback please - i.e. `A` for the first row, `B` for the second etc?

```
import tkinter as tk

NUM_ROWS = 5
BOLD_FONT = ("calbri", 16, "bold")
NORMAL_FONT = ("calbri", 16, "normal")


def submit():
    print("you win")


def clear(key):
    print(key)
    # widgets[key]["factor_field"].delete(0,"end")
    # widgets[key]["factor_field"].insert(0, key)


data = {}
widgets = {}

root = tk.Tk()

# Build widgets
for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
    key = chr(i + 65)
    this_row = widgets[key] = {}
    this_row["label"] = tk.Label(root, text=key, font=BOLD_FONT)
    this_row["label"].grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
    this_row["factor_field"] = tk.Entry(root, width=60, font=NORMAL_FONT)
    this_row["factor_field"] .grid(row=i, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
    this_row["target_node_field"] = tk.Entry(root, width=5, font=NORMAL_FONT)
    this_row["target_node_field"].grid(row=i, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)
    this_row["clear_button"] = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", command=lambda: clear(
        key), font=BOLD_FONT).grid(row=i, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)

submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit,
                          font=BOLD_FONT).grid(row=NUM_ROWS + 1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)

print(widgets)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `command=lambda key=key: clear(key)` instead of command=lambda: clear(key) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
this_row["clear_button"] = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", 
                                     command=lambda x=key: clear(x), 
                                     font=BOLD_FONT)
this_row["clear_button"].grid(row=i, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)
```

In your current code, the value for the `key` variable is fixed at `E` after the `for` loop has completed. As a result, your existing lambda function will always call `clear('E')`.